# Draw Squares of colors inside a JFrame GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

how by using a GUI create 9 different squares distributed in a grid of 3 rows and 3 columns
on a frame. The user will be able to change the color of any part just by pressing the right click and a menu will be shown to choose the desired color

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Coloring extends JPanel
{
private JRadioButtonMenuItem items[];
private Color colorValue[]={Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.PINK,Color.GRAY,Color.YELLOW,Color.CYAN,Color.MAGENTA,Color.BLACK};

public Coloring()
{


    final JPopupMenu popupMenu=new JPopupMenu();
    ItemHandler handler =new ItemHandler();
    String colors[]={"Green","Blue","Red","Pink","Gray","Yellow","Cyan","Magenta","Black"};
    ButtonGroup colorGroup= new ButtonGroup();
    items=new JRadioButtonMenuItem[9];

    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
    {
        items[i]=new JRadioButtonMenuItem(colors[i]);
        popupMenu.add(items[i]);
        colorGroup.add(items[i]);
        items[i].addActionListener(handler);
    }
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Colored Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(new Square());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        { checkForTrigerEvent(e); }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        { checkForTrigerEvent(e); }

        public void checkForTrigerEvent(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.isPopupTrigger())
                popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    }
    );
}
private class ItemHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
            if(e.getSource()==items[i])
            {
                getContentPane().setBackground(colorValue[i] );
                repaint();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D) g.create();

    int width=getWidth();
    int height=getHeight();

    int cellWidth= width/3;
    int cellHeight=height/3;

    int xOffset=(width - (3*cellWidth))/2;
    int yOffset=(height -(3*cellHeight))/2;

}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Coloring();
}
}
```

**Now i have no idea how i can addd the squares that will change the color on right click **

Comment: Use `GridLayout` on frame, add 9 `JComponents` with prefered size to it, now add `JPopupMenu` to those jcomponents.

Comment: @Arvind This should be posted as an answer rather than simply a comment

Comment: This is not a "write my code for me" website. If you have a particular problem with your code, then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a good description of your problem; then people will be able to help.

Comment: @Arvind can you please recheck my edit ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt excuse me for my mistake i didn't know how to begin , now can you please help me and check my edit ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to break this down into several smaller parts kind of like how Arvind explained in the comments.

Use GridLayout on frame, add 9 JComponents with prefered size to it, now add JPopupMenu to those jcomponents.

I recommend looking at the following

GridLayout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

JComponents http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html

Like people said above this website is for help with issues not to do the work for you. Good luck with your adventure.

*UPDATE*

There are plenty of different ways you can do this but I suggest you change BorderLayout to GridLayout(0,3) this will automatically position the JComponents so that they are evenly positioned in the JFrame. I then suggest you add 9 JComponents or (I prefer to use JPanels) to the JFrame instead of whatever you are doing with adding the Square. you will then want to add Action listeners to each JComponent here is an example of how you can use an action listener to detect the right click.

```
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
       {
        if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) //this checks for a right mouse click
        popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
       }

       public void checkForTrigerEvent(MouseEvent e)
       {
       }
   }
   );
```

Comment: can you please explain to me more what do you mean to replace it with panel instead of JFrame ?